# Using bitmapped Monaco in Textmate

Tags: font, textmate

When I use TextWrangler, I can use the beautiful, crisp bitmapped 10 point Monaco font:

[image: bitmap]

In TextMate, when I select Monaco 10 as my font, I get a much fuzzier rendered vector graphic from the TrueType version of Monaco:

[image]

I do like the lack of chrome in a TextMate window, but find the lack of bitmapped Monaco 10 to be off-putting. Is there a way to get TextMate to use the bitmapped version of the Monaco font, or do I need to stick with TextWrangler for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For TextMate 2 you can do the following.

In a Terminal window run:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview disableAntiAlias -bool YES
```

To disable it, run:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview disableAntiAlias -bool NO
```

Comment: Alas it applies to all fonts, and not just desired fonts, but this is good to know about!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about TextMate 2, but there's an option to disable anti-aliasing in TextMate 1.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is that in the font dialog box? If so, it's a feature not (yet?) found in the alpha release of 2.